# How to find function to match spectific data in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

we have to find data if this key-value exists together.

**1**. **orgId** = PQR

**2**. **tagId** = 123

This is array of objects.

```
    [{
       "_id" : "c6114ee0",
         orders:[{
            "orgId" : "ABC",
            "tagId" : "123"
            },
           {"orgId": "PQR",
            "tagId": "456"
           },
           {"orgId": "XYZ"
           }
         ]
    },
    {
       "_id" : "c6114ee1",
         orders:[{
            "orgId" : "SDE",
            "tagId" : "446"
            },
           {"orgId": "PQR",
            "tagId": "123"
           },
           {"orgId": "UJI"
           }
         ]
    }]
```

output

```
      {
       "_id" : "c6114ee1",
         orders:[
           {"orgId": "PQR",
            "tagId": "123"
           }
         ]
       }
```

we have used this condition

> db.collection.find(**{"orders.orgId":"PQR","orders.tagId":"123"**},function(err, result){
>    })

it returns both documents.

**NOTE:**
 *we have not be used aggregate*

Answer (score 1):

Just search as an object, not separated items.

Example:

```
db.collection.find(
    { "orders": { "orgId":"PQR", "tagId":"123" } },
    { "orders.$": 1 }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.$` operator to select only matched array element

```
db.collection.find({"orders.orgId":"PQR","orders.tagId":"123"}, 
                   {"orders.$":1}, 
                   function(err, result){ })
```

Comment: This will match all documents where `orders` contains some item with `orgId: "PQR"` and a potentially different item with `tagId: "123"`. Try it against the sample data and you will see two documents returned...